# Send Push from CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, urbanairship.com

I need to send a push message from Urban Airship. To do this I have to send an API request from CakePHP.
My question: where should i put the code for the API request in CakePHP? In the model or in the controller? Where is the correct place for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I follow [Neil Crookes'](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2010/12/24/neil_crookes_-_designing_cakephp_plugins_for_consuming_apis/playlist:4d14370c-0610-4e56-a6f2-57a282f0cb67) idea of keeping the logic in the datasource. An API is really just a datasource, after all. Then, models are introduced as the various endpoints the API has. For example, I have a [Stripe plugin](https://github.com/jeremyharris/stripe) that follows this model. A StripeCustomer model then has a `$path` variable that the datasource uses as the endpoint.

This model has several benefits:

1. API calls are integrated with the ORM - so they look like regular model finds and saves
2. You can utilize built in validation, callbacks, behaviors, etc.
3. Very DRY and therefore easy to debug and test